# Трудо- и финансово затратный

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, дефис

Есть вот такая часть предложения:

*...Менее привлекательный вариант, так как более трудо- и финансово затратный.*

Сомневаюсь в написании словосочетания "трудо- и финансово затратный". Правильно ли будет такое написание? Если нет, то как будет правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что дефис поставить нужно.

*Финансово затратный* пишется раздельно, но ***трудозатратный*** пишется слитно. Так что союз *и* разбивает слово *трудозатратный* на 2 части, из-за чего и возникает потребность в дефисе.

А если наоборот (***финансово и трудозатратный***), то, на мой взгляд, дефис не нужен, так как, как я и сказал, *финансово затратный* пишется раздельно, поэтому нет оснований ставить дефис.

Так что:

***Трудо- и финансово затратный***.